# How to inject meta data in existing object

Tags: python, testing, mocking, metaprogramming

Sometimes, i need to change existing method behaviour or inject meta data for testing purpouses. Like: we have 2 predefined classes which we can't change (we can implement SomeClass* just to ease injecting metadata).

```
class A(SomeClass1):
    def __init__(self):
        last_id = self.id

class B(SomeClass2):
   def __init__(self):
        last_id = self.id
```

So what should be done to next line print incremented id's (like: 1 2 3) ?

```
print A().id, B().id, A().id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that i should create metaclass with **__call__** method and reinitialize classes with my metaclass like in example below:

```
collector = 0


class IdMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        global collector
        collector += 1
        cls.id = collector
        return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwds)


A = IdMeta(A.__name__, A.__bases__, dict(A.__dict__))
B = IdMeta(B.__name__, B.__bases__, dict(B.__dict__))
```